# Action Bar Sherlock like UItoolbar dark

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I found this library and liked it. Know i am searching info how to use it. I am creating app which support from SDK 2.1 to 4.*.

So i downloaded ActionBarSherlock version 4.0. Imported library and made dependence to that library. I was needed to use Api level 15, because it is requirement for library usage.

So i imported project Demo from samples.
Everything look fine, but i really don't like this:

```
[2012-03-29 11:18:46 - SampleList] Displaying it with 'Locale Language ___Region __, sw320dp, w320dp, h533dp, Normal Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, Trackball navigation, Screen resolution 800x480' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

However i need this library creating navigation bar on top of all my layouts and change buttons action up to which layout i am.

So my target is to do this NavigationBar:

[image]

Maybe someone have done this with ActionBarsherlock and could help me ?

Also is it possible with ActionbarSherlock to do on Top Navigation Bar and on buttom Tab Bar with images ?

it should look similar:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Don't know why the people try to make android application exactly like iPhone. Android has it's own components. Please don't make it ugly.

Comment: @Shaiful i second your emotion ... http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: I had developed my app on iOS now want to do the same on Android. I want same design.

Comment: @Selvin - Android is great. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The library was designed to mimic the Ice Cream Sandwich action bar which has fundamental differences in both design and interaction patterns. I'm fairly certain that you could bastardize ActionBarSherlock into looking somewhat like UIToolbar, but it would be far easier to just create custom views to do this for you.

Also, ***please do not do this***. Not a single Android user on the planet will thank you an iOS interface on an Android device.

http://developer.android.com/design/index.html